# Create a table with count of columns, count of rows, count of NA in row , out of dataframes in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, summary, datalist

I am refreshing my knowledge of R... and I am struggling :)
I really need your help. What I want to do is to create a data table like that:

```
data source name | nrow | ncol | count if NA
data source1 | 23 | 3 | 2
data source2 | 2 | 21 | na
data source3.... and so on.
```

Data sources are data frames nested in a list.
What I did so far:

```
columns <- lapply(list, length) 
rows <-sapply(list,nrow)
```

when I am trying to merge these two - impossible. Also do not know how to get the NA from rows.

the sample of the data is in the list and it looks like this:

`list: data source1 : column1: run1; column2: run2; column3: run3....; data source2: column1: net; column2: gross;....` 
How can I create a simple table with the outlook I am looking for? should I run it through the loop?

Comment: ignore it, just figured out: rows<-  lapply(list, nrow)
columns<-  lapply(list,length)
data.table(names(list), rows,columns). Officially I need a to start an r tutorial :D

Comment: that comment is not helpful - people will only see it after they read the problem. Please consider writing an answer and maybe even accepting it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=Yes!,to%20answer%20their%20own%20questions.&text=Alternatively%2C%20you%20may%20go%20back,48%20hours%20to%20do%20so.

Comment: I see, apologies - I had no idea :) Let me accept the answer now. Thank you so much

Comment: No need to apologize. It is just nice for the future if people see at first glance, which answers exist und which contain the prefered (by you) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(purrr)

df_list %>% 
  imap_dfr(~c(source = .y, nrow = nrow(.x), ncol = ncol(.x), NA_count = sum(is.na(.x))))
```

you can use this if `df_list` has names. If it doesnt then assign names to it:

```
names(df_list) <- source_vec
```

where `source_vec` is mapping source to data frames in `df_list`